# perl multithreading: lock to prevent race condition

Tags: multithreading, perl

```
lock (%{$j{$t}});
@keys = sort {${$j{$t}}{$a}{stime} cmp ${$j{$t}}{$b}{stime}
                    } keys %{$j{$t}};
```

I get "Invalid value for shared scalar" while sorting.
I noticed that I get this error if  $j{$t}}{$a} doesnt exists i.e. got deleted while sorting by another thread.

Doesnt `lock (%{$j{$t}});` prevents from the key in hash to be deleted?

Comment: `${$j{$t}}{$a}{stime}` is much more clearly written `$j{$t}->{$a}->{stime}` or `$j{$t}{$a}{stime}`. It would also help a lot to use meaningful variable names. `j`, `a`, and `t` mean nothing to me.

Comment: knowing what the variables are is irrelevant to the question being asked

Comment: I notice that the word "advisory" is bold in http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html#lock-VARIABLE .  Are you sure your other thread is trying to obtain it's own lock?

Comment: @tjd good catch! thats what i was missing

Comment: btw, your code would be much simpler if you assigned `$j{$t}` to a var and used that var instead of `$j{$t}` all over the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that the word "advisory" is bold in [lock's documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html#lock-VARIABLE). Make sure your other thread is trying to obtain its own lock.